# Find IP Addresses of Local Servers

Tags: c#, .net, networking, ip-address

I would like to retrieve the IP addresses of the server (or servers) on the local network dynamically. How can I retrieve these IP addresses?

---

Update with code from an answer:

```
// Query for all the enabled network adapters 
ManagementObjectSearcher objSearcher = new ManagementObjectSearcher(
   "SELECT * FROM Win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration WHERE IPEnabled='TRUE'");    
ManagementObjectCollection objCollection = objSearcher.Get();

// Loop through all available network interfaces
foreach (ManagementObject obj in objCollection)
{
   // List all IP addresses of the current network interface
   string[] AddressList = (string[])obj["IPAddress"];
   foreach (string Address in AddressList)
   {
      MessageBox.Show(Address);
   }
}
```

[code source](http://www.geekpedia.com/tutorial149_Get-the-IP-address-in-a-Windows-application.html)

I use this code but it only returns my own PC's IP address, not all the IPs in network.

Comment: what is your query-parameter to identify the server? machine-names? what are local servers? do you mean servers in your domain? please elaborate!

Comment: yes i mean servers in domain.thanks.

Comment: You say you only want servers, define a server

Comment: no, i want get ip dynamiclly.

Answer (score 1):

This could be quite difficult, depending on the configuration of the network. If it's solely a windows network, and the account you're running the application as has Administrator rights, it'll be a bit easier.

The best way would be to query your PDC (Primary Domain Controller). Check out the System.DirectoryServices.ActiveDirectory namespace.

If I remember correctly, you can use LDAP to query the domain controller - as long as the PDC is correctly configured! I found this LDAP query that may help you:

"(&(objectCategory=computer)(|(operatingSystem=Windows Server*)(operatingSystem=Windows 2000 Server))))))"

Of course, that will only query windows 2000 servers - you should be able to modify as needed.

Check out the following links:

http://www.google.co.uk/search?gcx=c&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=c%23+ldap+query

Answer (score 0):

[This](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/network.aspx) will let you get the IP address of a machine by name. Is that what you are looking for?

Comment: @na: this will let you get the IP for any machine on your network (that you can see) for which you have the name. How do you want to distinguish what is a "server?" Operating system?

Comment: do you have beter suggestion for distinguishing the server's ip??

Comment: @na: it really depends on how you define a machine as being a server, as @Jimmy and I have mentioned. Do you know the machine names for the "servers" for which you want the IPs? Otherwise, you need to decide on a way to distinguish the machines for which you want the IP from others on your network. Without knowing your business needs, I don't know what else to tell you.

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at a discovery protocol such as Apple's Bonjour (Zeroconf). [http://en.wikipedia.org](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bonjour_%28software%29)